# psql query groupby and count

Tags: sql, psql

I have table like:

```
the_geom | georte 

123          I
234          J
234          I
567          I
784          I
287          K
```

I need to write a query which would select the row which has more than 2 occurence of value of georte column for example I value has more than two occurence , so I want to get all the_geom value of I and group them based on georte.

Comment: How do you want to group them? Could you add the exact output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` and `HAVING` can be used.

```
SELECT * from tableA A
JOIN (  
    SELECT georte from tableA
    GROUP BY georte
    HAVING COUNT(*) >2
) T
ON A.georte = T.georte
```

Comment: put some explanation to your answer posted, this will help others to get it quickly.